# Prove that a sequence related with hypergeometric function is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

I want to prove that this sequence

$$A_n:=\frac{3^m \sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma\left[\frac{1}{2}+m\right] \text{Hypergeometric2F1}\left[\frac{1}{2},1,1+m,\frac{3}{4}\right]}{2 \,\,\Gamma[m+1]}$$

is increasing $\forall n=1,2,3...$

I've tried with classical methods $A_{n}-A_{n+1}<0$ or $\displaystyle\frac{A_n}{A_{n+1}}<1$ but I'm not able.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: @Somos. It seems to be $\left\{\pi ,2 \pi ,\frac{19 \pi }{4},\frac{97 \pi }{8},\frac{2059 \pi }{64}\right\}$

Comment: Notice that the ratio $\frac{_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;m+2;\frac{3}{4}\right)} {_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;m+1;\frac{3}{4}\right)}$ is an increasing function going asymptotically to $1$. For $m=10$, this ratio is $\frac{22217196067}{22291578666}$

Comment: If you want fun, plot $\log(a_m)$ as a function of $m$. It is almost a straight line with a slope $\approx \log(3)$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I do not know how much this could help.*

If 
$$a_m=\frac{ 3^m \sqrt{\pi }\,\,\Gamma
   \left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma (m+1)}\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;m+1;\frac{3}{4}\right)$$ then
$$\frac{a_{m+1}}{a_m}=\frac{3(2m+1) }{2(m+1) }\frac{_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;m+2;\frac{3}{4}\right)} {_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;m+1;\frac{3}{4}\right)}$$

Now, in [this page](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/ShowAll.html), the fourth recurrence identity for consecutive neighbors may be of interest. For large $m$, it seems that 
$$\frac{a_{m+1}}{a_m}\approx\frac{3(2m+1) }{2(m+1) }=3-\frac{3}{2 (m+1)}\approx 3$$

**Edit**

Just for the fun of playing with small numbers, I produced a table of 
$$b_m=\frac{_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;m+2;\frac{3}{4}\right)} {_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;m+1;\frac{3}{4}\right)}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
m & b_m \\
 1 & \frac{8}{9} \\
 2 & \frac{19}{20} \\
 3 & \frac{388}{399} \\
 4 & \frac{10295}{10476} \\
 5 & \frac{22382}{22649} \\
 6 & \frac{865445}{872898} \\
 7 & \frac{5527624}{5563575} \\
 8 & \frac{93494361}{93969608} \\
 9 & \frac{1769172910}{1776392859} \\
 10 & \frac{22217196067}{22291578666} \\
 11 & \frac{46324620476}{46454137231} \\
 12 & \frac{3466132816211}{3474346535700}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: many thanks for your answers

Comment: Finally I've arrived to the proof. I didn't write cause is a little complicated but if you are interested, I can post it.

Comment: @popi. Good to know ! For sure, I am interested and I guess that other people would be. It could be good you post an answer to your own question. Cheers.